# Send email when condition is true in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, email

I'm trying, in Symfony, to send an email automatically at any moment when the condition is true but my code is not working, I don't know if need to put it in a different method or in a special condition, or if I need messenger to do that. If someone can help me, thank you.

Controller.php :

```
class CandidatureController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/candidature', name: 'app_candidature', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request, MailerInterface $mailer): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()->getIsApproved() == false or $this->getUser()->isIsVerified() == false) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('not approved');
        }
        $candidature = new Candidature();

        $candidatRepo = $doctrine->getRepository(ProfileCandidat::class,); // access to the repository of ProfileCandidat
        $candidatNom = $candidatRepo->findOneBy([
            'email_adress' => $this->getUser()->getEmail()
        ]);

        $annonce = $entityManager->getRepository(Annonce::class)->findOneBy([
            'id' => $request->get('id')
        ]);


        //dd($candidatNom->getNom()); // display the name of the specific ProfileCandidat with the id

        $candidature->setNom($candidatNom->getNom());    // set the name of the ProfileCandidat in the Candidature
        $candidature->setPrenom($candidatNom->getPrenom()); // set the lastname of the ProfileCandidat in the Candidature
        $candidature->setCv($candidatNom->getCV()); // set the cv of the ProfileCandidat in the Candidature
        $candidature->setAnnonce($annonce); // set the annonce_id in the Candidature

        $entityManager->persist($candidature);
        $entityManager->flush();

        if ($candidature->getIsVerified() == true) {
            $email = (new Email())
                ->from('trtconseilexample@gmail.com')
                ->to($annonce->getEmail())
                ->subject('Vous avez un nouveau candidat !')
                ->text("{$candidature->getNom()} {$candidature->getPrenom()} a postulé à votre annonce, vous trouverez son CV en pièce jointe !")
                ->attachFromPath("public/uploads/images/{$candidature->getCv()}");
            ;
            $mailer->send($email);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_annonce_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

}
```

EDIT :
I tried to do an event listener when the entity is postupdate but it doesn't work either

```
class MailEvent
{
// the entity listener methods receive two arguments:
// the entity instance and the lifecycle event
public function postUpdate(Candidature $candidature, Annonce 
$annonce, MailerInterface $mailer, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
{
    $change = $event->getEntityChangeSet();

    if ($change instanceof Candidature and $candidature->getIsVerified()) {
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('trtconseilexample@gmail.com')
            ->to($annonce->getEmail())
            ->subject('Vous avez un nouveau candidat !')
            ->text("{$candidature->getNom()} {$candidature->getPrenom()} a postulé à votre annonce, vous trouverez son CV en pièce jointe !")
            ->attachFromPath("public/uploads/images/{$candidature->getCv()}");
        ;
        $mailer->send($email);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a cron job that runs a custom symfony command, create one to run every minute for example. Create a custom command that loops all users, if they are verified and approved it sends an email (and whatever else you need to do). Maybe another way but thats my take...

Comment: The best way to do this is to use commands/events for the primary actions (approving/verifying), then add an event listener for those events that checks and creates the notification command that sends the email when the conditions are met.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

Comment: So I tried to add an event listener when the entity is updating but I think I messed up something